# How to write two dot above a letter?

Tags: math-mode, accents

the two dots above a letter represents two derivative of varible t.

My method:

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\begin{equation}
\"{o}
\mathaccent{o} 
\end{equation}
```

However,the latex says in the math environment ,I must use the `\mathaccent`. So I replace `\"` by `\mathaccent`, but it shows the warning information: `Missing number, treated as zero`

I am a starter, I want to know how to revise it? Can someone help me? Thanks sincerely!!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Use `$\dot x$` for the first derivative, `\ddot x` for the second, `\dddot  x` for the third, `\ddddot x` for the fourth.

Comment: @Peter Grill,Thaks for your warm welcome and solution.I am a college student.I like Latex very much.

Comment: @ Peter Grill,Dear  Peter Grill,BTW,how to write the "^" above a letter.`\^{u}` cannot achieve that effect in the math enviroment.

Comment: `$\hat{u}$`....

Comment: I would like to extend this question and ask how one would do the same thing only under the letter or a word

Comment: Is there a way to generalise the number of dots with the number of 'd' in `dot` ? @PeterGrill

Comment: You might try unicode directly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_(diacritic)

Answer (score 199, accepted):

The sequence

```
\"{o}
```

will be used when you want to write '**ö**' in text, such as 'Schrödinger'.
While in the math mode, as Peter Grill mentioned

```
\dot{o}
\ddot{o}
```

and so on, should do the trick.

**Edit:**

For more than two dots, e.g. `\dddot{o}`, you need the package `amsmath`, which allows you a maximum of 4 dots  `\ddddot{o}`
(not strikingly beautiful 
[image: fourth time derivative])

For higher dot derivatives take a look at [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186336/what-is-the-correct-way-to-typeset-higher-order-time-derivatives-in-latex)

Comment: what package do you need in order to use `\"`? it does not seem to work by default.

Comment: It should work in the text mode without any additional packages. I checked with only `\documentclass{article}\begin{document} Thr\"{o}ugh \end{document}`

Comment: How did you type ````\"```` ? When I try typing ````\"````, it does not work, but when I copy/paste your code, it does.

Comment: It's simply a backslash and a double quotation mark.

Comment: @Allure wanted to type `\"`. Your LaTeX IDE may substitute left or right quotation-marks when you type the double-quote key on your keyboard. You can change your IDE preferences to eliminate such LaTeX substitutions. Within many IDEs with default substition, you may still copy & paste a double-quote or you may use a GUI menu to input a double-quote (e.g., "international accents").