# What is the correct way to typeset higher order time derivatives in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode

I am typing a series that involves higher order time derivatives, and I have two main problems.

First, the subscript of the derived variable seems to move further away from it with the more characters on top, is there a way to fix that?

Second, what is the best way to typeset an nth order derivative without it being too big as in `\overset{(n)}{V}`, or too high as in `\overset{{}^{(n)}}{V}`?

Here is an example that shows all the mentioned problems:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
 $\displaystyle
 \dot{V}_t = \dot{V}_{t-1} + \ddot{V}_{t-1} dt + \frac{\dddot{V}_{t-1}dt^2}{2} +
 \frac{\overset{(4)}{V}_{t-1}dt^3}{6} + \dots + \frac{\overset{{}^{(n+1)}}{V}_{t-1}dt^n}{n!}
 $
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

EDIT:

`\overset{\text{\tiny $(n)$}}{V}` works for reducing the size of the overset, but the subscript distance is still a problem

EDIT 2:

The subscript distance can be reduced by adding negative spaces as in `\frac{\overset{{}^{(n+1)}}{V}_{\!\!\!t-1}dt^n}{n!}`. I'm not sure if it's the cleanest way to do it, but it works

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's probably no single or unique "correct" way to typeset this expression, but

- using `\scriptscriptstyle` for the overset terms `(4)` and `(n+1)`,
- using `\mathclap` to "smash" the width of the term  `(n+1)`, and
- inserting a thinspace, `\,`,  in front of the `dt` terms

may be what you need:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathclap macro
\begin{document}
\[
 \dot{V}_t = \dot{V}_{t-1} + 
 \ddot{V}_{t-1} \,dt + 
 \frac{\dddot{V}_{t-1}\,dt^2}{2} +
 \frac{\overset{\scriptscriptstyle(4)}{V}_{t-1}\,dt^3}{6} + \dots + 
 \frac{\overset{\mathclap{\scriptscriptstyle(n+1)}}{V}_{t-1}\,dt^n}{n!}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

I would just put them as ordinary superscripts.  For the third derivative it seems to be necessary to backspace the subscript a bit:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \dot{V}_t = \dot V_{t-1} + \ddot V_{t-1} dt +
  \frac{\dddot V_{\!t-1}dt^2}{2} + \frac{V^{(4)}_{t-1}dt^3}{6} +
  \dots + \frac{V^{(n+1)}_{t-1}dt^n}{n!}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

If, as in your case, this notation is used for something else than I would recommend using a differential operator instead:

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \dot{V}_t = \dot V_{t-1} + \ddot V_{t-1} dt +
  \frac{(D^3_t V)_{t-1}dt^2}{2} + \frac{(D^4_tV)_{t-1}dt^3}{6} +
  \dots + \frac{(D^{n+1}_tV)_{t-1}dt^n}{n!}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In the notation I'm using, ordinary subscripts are reserved for the positional derivatives ``$\frac{dy}{dx}$``. I use oversets for time derivatives

Comment: Especially for the 3rd derivative, you could need, something nicer, like  ![enter image description here][1]

`$\overset{\therefore}{V}$`


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zF9DT.png

Comment: @cis That is not a standard notation.

Comment: I know, but you and I are not standard-human-beeings, so we could think in categories, like meaningful and nice too ;)  PS: I saw this notatation in some scripts from professors, so: why not.

Answer (score 4):

Just to complete the answers of Mico and Andrew:

[In Wikipedia, the dot notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Newton.27s_notation) for derivatives higher than the third (i.e.,  `\ddot{V}`    [image: third dot derivative V]) is  `\overset{n}{\dot{V}}`

[image]

(that is, the *n-th* dot derivative)

**Example:**

[image]

(code: `\overset{5}{\dot{V}} \equiv \frac{d^5V}{dt^5}`)